# Get info from 2 separate Mongo documents in one mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im using MongoDb, and I have a workspace schema with mongoose (v4.0.1):

```
var Workspace = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    "default": Date.now
  }
});
```

And a user schema:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  organisation: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  verifyString: {
    type: String
  },
  verified: {
    type: Boolean, 
    default: false 
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    "default": Date.now
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean, 
    default: false 
  }
});
```

So the `Workspace userId` is the `ObjectID` from the `User` document.

When Im logged in as an adminstrator, I want to get all workspaces, as well as the email of the user that owns the workspace.

What Im doing is getting very messy:

```
Workspace.find({}).exec.then(function(workspaceObects){

   var userPromise = workspaceObects.map(function(workspaceObect){
        // get the user model with workspaceObect.userId here
   });

   // somehow combine workspaceObjects and users
```

});

The above doesnt work and gets extremely messy. Basically I have to loop through the `workspaceObjects` and go retrieve the user object from the workspace `userId`. But because its all promises and it becomes very complex and easy to make a mistake.

Is there a much simpler way to do this? In SQL it would require one simple join. Is my schema wrong? Can I get all workspaces and their user owners email in one Mongoose query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Workspace = new mongoose.Schema({  
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'  //add this to your schema
  }  
});

Workspace.find().populate('userId').exec( (err, res) => {
   //you will have res with all user fields
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: np. If you want to join without mongoose, see "lookup aggregation operator" in mongoDB, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 1):

Mongo don't have joins but mongoose provides a very powerfull tool to help you with you have to change the model a little bit and use populate:
 [Mongoose population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

You have to make a few changes to your models and get the info of the user model inside your workspace model.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, im using the populate method now and have changed schema, works great